# change sms notification sound using broadcastreceiver

Tags: android, notifications, sms

i am using broadcast reciver to get the new received sms and check if it contains a word to change mobile sms notification sound using another sound in my sdcard
how to do it
this is my code

```
if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)){


        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        try {
            if (bundle != null) {
                final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                    String address = currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress();

                    String smsBody = currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody();

if (smsBody.contains("hello")){


//there i need to change notification sound and mute the base mobile notification and use another sound from sdcard


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION,uriOfAudioFile);
```

Comment: my friend i use a code in Service and start service when sms received.. but when i receive sms there is no sound notification.. why? i will past my code in answer

Comment: how i can put uriOfAudioFile from SD card?

Comment: Uri.fromFile(filepath)